# pyparsing lineno issue (bug?)

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using pyparsing to parse a language called pig. I found some unexpected result when used the function 'lineno' when the input text have some '\t' in it.

For easy to ask, I simplified the code to address the problem:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
from pyparsing import *

ident = Word(alphas)
statement1 = ident + Literal('=')+ Keyword('GENERATE', caseless = True) + SkipTo(Literal(';'),ignore = nestedExpr())+ Literal(';').suppress()
statement2 = Keyword('STORE',caseless = True) + ident + Literal(';').suppress()
statement = statement1|statement2

text = """
fact = GENERATE
('Exp' :(a
                )
)  ;

STORE fact ;


"""

all_statements = statement.scanString(text)
for tokens,startloc,endloc in all_statements:
        print 'startloc:' + str(startloc) , 'lineno:' + str(lineno(startloc,text))
        print 'endloc:' + str(endloc), 'lineno:' + str(lineno(endloc,text))
        print tokens
```

Notice that in the input text, there is more than 3 '\t' in the beginning of the third line
When I run this , the output is :

```
startloc:1 lineno:2
endloc:66 lineno:10
['fact', '=', 'GENERATE', "('Exp' :(a\n                                )\n)  "]
startloc:68 lineno:10
endloc:80 lineno:10
['STORE', 'fact']
```

this should be wrong, as there is total 9 line, it said the first statement is from line 2 to line 10.
I happened to found that when I delete those '\t', the input text is :

```
text = """
fact = GENERATE
('Exp' :(a
)
)  ;

STORE fact ;


"""
```

and I run it again, the result is :

```
startloc:1 lineno:2
endloc:34 lineno:5
['fact', '=', 'GENERATE', "('Exp' :(a\n)\n)  "]
startloc:36 lineno:7
endloc:48 lineno:7
['STORE', 'fact']
```

And this result seems correct, the first statement is from line 2 to line 5, the second statemenet is from line 7 to line 7 .This is what I expected.

So I think there maybe something wrong in the lineno() function, or maybe scanString.
Or maybe there is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [parseWithTabs](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#parseWithTabs) before calling `scanString`.